# How to use PostSharp LoggingAspect in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, postsharp

I am trying to execute some logging logic after a method is done executing. So, I used the basic example described here by Postsharp as follows:

```
[PSerializable]
public class LoggingAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
  public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("The {0} method has exited.", args.Method.Name);
  }     
}
```

Then, I try to use this attribute `LoggingAspect` on different methods. It works on all methods except those in the controller class like the following:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [LoggingAspect]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get(string number, int? year)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I expected the attribute `LoggingAspect` to work on all methods, however it did not work in the controller. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you use ActionFilterAttribute instead of Postsharp?

Comment: Because I have other projects in the solution, and I want to unify the way I execute the logging.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue, but for me, your scenario works. (I've executed the API project using "dotnet run" and after getting a result from an IEnumerable controller, I've seen the "The Get method has exited." in console.) Could you please share a project reproducing the issue? You can also use PostSharp Logging, which is already implemented. See https://www.postsharp.net/logging.

Comment: Are you sure PostSharp package is referenced in the project you are using the attribute in? NuGet does not use build-time part of packages from referenced projects. You need to have explicit PackageReference in each project in which you are using aspects.

Comment: @DanielBalas That's exactly what I was missing. It works now! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was not referencing Postsharp in the project I was using the `LoggingAspect` attribute in. It wasn't obvious at first as there were no build or runtime errors in that project.